# MediaWiki Api- within category text search

Tags: mediawiki-api

While I can get a list of pages within a specific category using 'categorymembers', how do i refine the search limiting results to those containing specific text? 
For example i want to search the Physics category limiting results to those pages containing the text "force". Is there a way to do this or do you have to combine search term as
"physics force"?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to refine the search in this way via the API. You would have to post-process the results on the client side in whatever manner you need.

Comment: Actually, it can be done on MediaWiki: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28412/search-within-a-category-on-a-mediawiki-site/29455#29455

Comment: The above-mentioned StackExchange solution does not work as of 2014-12. It locates only non-transcluded category tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can include category as part of search string.

Here is [an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&list=search&utf8=1&srsearch=Nelson%20incategory%3A20th-century_South_African_politicians)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30702028)